# Multiple display setup mac, ignore separation between displays

Tags: macos, display, macbook-pro

I am currently setting up my workstation, and I want to use the set up pictured here:

[image]

As you can see, the display on the top is turned sideways, and that is the way I want it.

The question is this: how can I make the cursor jump between the left and right monitors and the top monitor smoothly (rather, at all), as if the top display was just as wide as the bottom center display? Right now, the cursor can't cross directly over the separation between the top and the side displays.

The desired behavior is that which would result if the top display was just as wide as the bottom, so there wouldn't be any disconnect between the displays. However, I want to keep the top display oriented at its current orientation.

I am using a retina macbook pro, early 2013, on OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: That is a pretty nice setup. But I don't a believe the cursor will transition between displays that are not touching although I have never tried the type of configuration you have there.

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right: I don't think there is a way without some kind of work-around or third party solution. That solution is the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

That's not really what you wanted, but have you tried this arrangement?

[image: setup]

Comment: That is an option. The only problem with this is the physical layout of the monitors. It would make moving the mouse from one display to the next a bit awkward (non-correlate spatially to the physical setup).